# VIsual Studio not showing .db files in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to read a database file for a Xamarin project that I'm creating and I added the **.db** file (database) in an "Assets" folder according to some tutorial. I'm 100% sure that the file is present, but the **Solution Explorer** does not show the file and when I run the program, it says that the file does not exist.

Any suggestions to make the file part of the project?

Comment: did you add it to Assets using Visual Studio?

Comment: No, directly from the directories...

Comment: you have to use Solution Explorer in VS to add files to your projects.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ferpujolf If you solved your problem, please share your reply and mark your reply as answer, it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.